# Alter default response time in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'd like to set up custom response times for some of my intents in Dialogflow. Is there any way to delay the response time in default responses? For reference, if I were to ask the question "Is there anything else I can help you with?" after a previous response, I'd like to have this language delayed for a better user experience. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature as far as I know on Dialogflow. The responses and the rich responses [1,2] do not support this delays and it seems to be the intended behavior.

[1] -
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-responses

[2] -
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages